# PHP Script error running

Tags: php

So I created a script that gets data from a api then sends that data into the database. Now everything runs fine when the script has only 8 values going into the database. But when I put 9 Values going into the database it gives error.

This is the current code I have that gives the error:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// masteryinfo class
include_once "get_playerData_riot.php";
function storeData($conn, $apiKey, $sumNameOrId, $table) {
    // clear any bugged info
    if (gettype($sumNameOrId) == 'integer') {
        $fixquery = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=".$sumNameOrId;
        $resultfix = $conn->query($fixquery);
        if($resultfix->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rowfix = $resultfix->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($rowfix['champs_info'] == 'N;') {
                    $deletequery = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=".$sumNameOrId;
                    if($conn->query($deletequery)) {
                        //echo 'reseted';
                    } else {
                        //echo 'didnt reseted';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $fixquery = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='".$sumNameOrId."'";
        $resultfix = $conn->query($fixquery);
        // var_dump($resultfix);
        if($resultfix->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rowfix = $resultfix->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($rowfix['champs_info'] == 'N;') {
                    $deletequery = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='".$sumNameOrId."'";
                    if($conn->query($deletequery)) {
                        //echo 'reseted';
                    } else {
                        //echo 'didnt reseted';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $time_limit = 3600; // 1 week
    $check_time = checkLimitTime($conn, $sumNameOrId, $table);

    if($check_time >= $time_limit || $check_time = NULL) {
        $sumname_f;
        if(gettype($sumNameOrId) == 'integer') {

            $sumname_f = (int)$sumNameOrId;
            // echo "<br>int passing <br>";
        } else {

            $sumname_f = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $sumNameOrId), 'UTF-8');
        }
        $playerData = new PlayerData($apiKey, $sumname_f);
        // echo $sumNameOrId;
        // echo mb_detect_encoding($sumNameOrId);
        $formatedName = str_replace(" ", "", $playerData->summonerData->name);
        $formatedName = mb_strtolower($formatedName, 'UTF-8');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (sum_id, sum_name, last_update, tier_info, ranked_champs_info, champs_info, summoner_info, player_match_history, player_runes, player_masteries)
            VALUES (
                ".$playerData->summonerData->id.",
                '".$formatedName."', NOW(),
                '".str_replace("'", "\'",serialize($playerData->getSummonerTier()))."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getRankedChampsInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getChampsInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getSummonerData())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getPlayerMatchHistoryInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getPlayerRunesInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getPlayerMasteriesInfo())."')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sum_name=VALUES(sum_name), champs_info=VALUES(champs_info), summoner_info=VALUES(summoner_info), last_update=NOW(), tier_info=VALUES(tier_info), ranked_champs_info=VALUES(ranked_champs_info), player_match_history=VALUES(player_match_history), player_runes=VALUES(player_runes), player_masteries=VALUES(player_masteries)";
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "Data has been stored for: ".$sumNameOrId;
        } else {
            if($playerData->summonerData = NULL) {
                header("Location: 404.php");
            } else {
                header("Location: 404.php");
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        // echo "Request limit reached for: ".$sumNameOrId;
        return false;
    }
}
function checkLimitTime($conn, $sumNameOrId, $table) {
    if(gettype($sumNameOrId) === 'integer') {
        $time_query =  "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update)) AS last_update FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=" . $sumNameOrId;
    } else {
        $formatedName = str_replace(" ", "", $sumNameOrId);
        $formatedName = mb_strtolower($formatedName, 'UTF-8');
        $time_query =  "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update)) AS last_update FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='" .$formatedName. "'";
    }
    $time_query_res = $conn->query($time_query);
    if($time_query_res->num_rows > 0) {
        $last_update =  $time_query_res->fetch_assoc();
        return $last_update['last_update'];
    } else {
        return 3600; // time limit completed need to put something better
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the code that works fine:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// masteryinfo class
include_once "get_playerData_riot.php";
function storeData($conn, $apiKey, $sumNameOrId, $table) {
    // clear any bugged info
    if (gettype($sumNameOrId) == 'integer') {
        $fixquery = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=".$sumNameOrId;
        $resultfix = $conn->query($fixquery);
        if($resultfix->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rowfix = $resultfix->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($rowfix['champs_info'] == 'N;') {
                    $deletequery = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=".$sumNameOrId;
                    if($conn->query($deletequery)) {
                        //echo 'reseted';
                    } else {
                        //echo 'didnt reseted';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $fixquery = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='".$sumNameOrId."'";
        $resultfix = $conn->query($fixquery);
        // var_dump($resultfix);
        if($resultfix->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rowfix = $resultfix->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($rowfix['champs_info'] == 'N;') {
                    $deletequery = "DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='".$sumNameOrId."'";
                    if($conn->query($deletequery)) {
                        //echo 'reseted';
                    } else {
                        //echo 'didnt reseted';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $time_limit = 3600; // 1 week
    $check_time = checkLimitTime($conn, $sumNameOrId, $table);

    if($check_time >= $time_limit || $check_time = NULL) {
        $sumname_f;
        if(gettype($sumNameOrId) == 'integer') {

            $sumname_f = (int)$sumNameOrId;
            // echo "<br>int passing <br>";
        } else {

            $sumname_f = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $sumNameOrId), 'UTF-8');
        }
        $playerData = new PlayerData($apiKey, $sumname_f);
        // echo $sumNameOrId;
        // echo mb_detect_encoding($sumNameOrId);
        $formatedName = str_replace(" ", "", $playerData->summonerData->name);
        $formatedName = mb_strtolower($formatedName, 'UTF-8');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (sum_id, sum_name, last_update, tier_info, ranked_champs_info, champs_info, summoner_info, player_match_history, player_runes)
            VALUES (
                ".$playerData->summonerData->id.",
                '".$formatedName."', NOW(),
                '".str_replace("'", "\'",serialize($playerData->getSummonerTier()))."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getRankedChampsInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getChampsInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getSummonerData())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getPlayerMatchHistoryInfo())."',
                '".serialize($playerData->getPlayerRunesInfo())."')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sum_name=VALUES(sum_name), champs_info=VALUES(champs_info), summoner_info=VALUES(summoner_info), last_update=NOW(), tier_info=VALUES(tier_info), ranked_champs_info=VALUES(ranked_champs_info), player_match_history=VALUES(player_match_history), player_runes=VALUES(player_runes)";
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "Data has been stored for: ".$sumNameOrId;
        } else {
            if($playerData->summonerData = NULL) {
                header("Location: 404.php");
            } else {
                header("Location: 404.php");
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        // echo "Request limit reached for: ".$sumNameOrId;
        return false;
    }
}
function checkLimitTime($conn, $sumNameOrId, $table) {
    if(gettype($sumNameOrId) === 'integer') {
        $time_query =  "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update)) AS last_update FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_id=" . $sumNameOrId;
    } else {
        $formatedName = str_replace(" ", "", $sumNameOrId);
        $formatedName = mb_strtolower($formatedName, 'UTF-8');
        $time_query =  "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update)) AS last_update FROM ".$table." WHERE sum_name='" .$formatedName. "'";
    }
    $time_query_res = $conn->query($time_query);
    if($time_query_res->num_rows > 0) {
        $last_update =  $time_query_res->fetch_assoc();
        return $last_update['last_update'];
    } else {
        return 3600; // time limit completed need to put something better
    }
}
?>
```

The database is setup 100% correct and is totally okay. Just somereason when I run with 9 values going to the database the script wont run and it will go to 404.php. Even when the user im getting data from exists.

Comment: Use `die($conn->error);` when the query fails, instead of redirecting to another page. Then you'll see the reason for the error.

Comment: Where abouts would be best?

Comment: Instead of the `else` block that does `header("Location: 404.php");`

Comment: What's the difference between the two versions?

Comment: Here is the problem

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's)";s:7:"current";b:0;s:9:"masteries";a:10:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"id";i:634' at line 11

Comment: The difference is in the insert of data to the data base

Comment: You really should use prepared queries instead of concatenating strings into the query.

Comment: `getPlayerMasteriesInfo()` probably has a quote in it, that's causing a syntax error when you substitute it into the SQL.

Comment: Is there anyway to resolve that? By maybe changing how the data is saved ? Like text or varchar ?

Comment: You see what you did with `str_replace()` for `getSummonerTier()`? That was for the same problem. You need to do that for the new argument. But if you're not going to use `bind_param()`, you should use `$conn->real_escape_string()`, rather than ad hoc string substitutions.

Comment: thanks you, was able to fix it using how i did for getSummonerTier().

Comment: I strongly recommend that you fix it by using a prepared query or `real_escape_string()`. Stop using bad practices, learn the right way.